# Android VerifyError issue

Tags: android, android-logcat

EDIT: to be more clear it only happens on android 2.2
hello guys please do help me with this issue. i'm getting this report 12 times on one day even tho i'v 1000+ installs. this issue start to appear now. and here is the logcat for it. 
please tell me whats wrong as i can't figure it out.

```
    java.lang.VerifyError: com.style.me.Smaller
at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1429)
at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1021)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2577)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:863)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:621)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: What is your question? And where is the code that causes the error?

Comment: its my main activity who causes this issue. it only happens on android 2.2. as you can see the logcat doesn't tell anything except it wont fire the activity. is not mentioning what's the cause of the issue. i'm doing some tests now. and i'll track the issue. or simply i'll stop my app of supporting the 2.2 . thanks for your reply btw. @Code-Guru

Comment: What is `com.style.me.Smaller`? When I run into similarly mysterious problems I add plenty of `Log.d()` calls to trace execution. Of course, the Eclipse debugger can help as well, but I haven't worked with it yet.

Comment: its my main class!. i reduced my app to support only from api 10 and above it was only causes on 2.2

Comment: I apologize that I wasn't clear. I was asking for some code in my indirect way. If you want help, we need code!